# What is the best way to track bugs in case of separate DEV and TEST team setup in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have many dev and test teams set up in TFS. Each team have their own backlog, and is set up under separate area path, i.e.

- Dev team is under area path 1
- Test team is under area path 2

Is there any way to track bugs raised by test team when they get assigned to Dev team? Currently the idea is to change are a path of the bug to area path 1 and iteration path to area path 1/Sprint number but with such set up, test team loose control over what is happening to the bugs they raised as they disappear from their backlog.

Comment: I can think of a few options, but it depends on how people are working, could you for example rely on work item linking? Have a Work Item on the Test Teams board linked to the bugs on the Dev teams board?

Comment: Hi, yes, it is critical to keep the link, as this seems to be the only way to keep track of those, but looking for some alternative options

Answer (score 0):

When your Test team perform testing, they can create a task that has many test cases, if one of the test cases fails when you test it, then you create a bug to track the defect, link the bug to the test case, and assign it to the Dev Team. When the Dev team fixes the bug, and pass the test case, Test team can close the bug. In this way, Test team can track the task on their side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is kind of what we do, but the worry is, that there is no easy solution to list all the bugs (or maybe there is, but I don't know about, hence my question). Also, I can't see a way to keep up with the progress of the bug, since it is in another area path and iteration now, it is not being shown on our board (web version). I can see some workarounds, but was wondering if any of TFS experts encountered the problem and found some neat solution

Comment: Maybe they can check the PBI tab, not Sprint tab.